# Seeing SSH debug messages in Terminal/console

Tags: ssh, terminal, logs, rsyslog

I am seeing "debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE" appear in the terminal on a RHEL 6 Linux server.  I thought maybe rsyslog had a console entry, but it doesn't.  sshd_config has logging at AUTHPRIV, and rsyslog sends authpriv to messages and secure only.  What could be happening?

Comment: can you please post the `ssh` command used? Have you used `-v` option? Also you might check the log level under `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for logging levels.

Comment: Check to see whether there is a logging specification for `root.` The logs may be appearing on the console simply because `root` is logged in.

Comment: Do you see only this specific message or other debug messages? Do you see these on the console (in text mode on the monitor connected over VGA/DVI/HDMI) or on some terminal where you're logged in? Is there an `ssh` or `sshd` process running with the option `-vvv` (or `-v -v -v` or equivalent)?

Comment: I have only noticed that one message, while logged in over an SSH session, initially logging in as a member of the wheel group, and then sudo -i to become root.  I saw it alot when trying to initiate an svn export over SSL to a remote server.  Nothing under SSH or rsyslog.conf seems relevant. IPTables is logging SSH, but that should only be going to /var/log/messages (which it is).  It happens whether I use -v in my SSH client args or not.  I didn't noticed it happening today though.